# Open and close Workbook or Instance in Excel 2016

Tags: c#, excel, interop, instance, excel-2016

We have an Excel Interop COM Add-in that performs the following at some point :

```
CurrentWorkbook.Close();
//other code
ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open("B.xls");
```

Let's say we have 1 workbook A.xls open. Up to Excel 2010, this worked as expected when the code is run: A is closed, and then B.xls is opened. I have read that since Excel 2013, each workbook is opened in its own Excel instance. Yet, even with Excel 2013 this behaved as expected above. No extra window is opened.

However, Excel 2016 has some modification that when A.xls is closed, an empty workbook shell remains. Afterwards, B.xls is opened in another window. So in the end I have 1 empty window and a window with B.xls.

It seems that the two windows are not independent : Closing B.xls does not create another empty Excel window, clicking close on the empty window actually will close B.xls.

Any ideas on how I should prevent the empty window when A is closed, or open B.xls in that empty window (which A left) as container and not a second window ?

Answer (score 0):

Under Startup options, you can turn off the "Show the start screen when this application starts" which reverts excel/word etc to revert to its former behavior

Comment: It's not the _start screen when this application starts_ , but the empty gray screen, with only menu bar, when the workbook is closed. Besides, I am not only talking about configuration so that MY machine would work. This product would be installed for clients so I would like to modify the behavior programmatically.

Comment: I get that empty screen the same in 2010 as I do in 2016 .. if you dont want an empty screen, you'll need to close excel

Comment: I am talking about the gray screen gotten after running _CurrentWorkbook.Close();_ and subsequently opening by Workbooks.Open(). I am not talking about clicking on the close workbook x button.

Comment: ok, so Im being super dense. I dont know which screen you mean.. and I spend a fair bit of time in excel.. so this isnt the no workbooks open excel window shell?

Comment: It's not the welcome screen https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/excel-2013-the/9781449359492/httpatomoreillycomsourceoreillyimages1622306.png.jpg if that's what you meant. It's the gray screen when all workbooks are closed. Like this http://cdn-7.officearticles.com/excel/images/no_wor5.jpg Not exactly Excel 2013-2016 but I hope it's comprehensive

Comment: Ok, but thats the empty screen, from closing all workbooks - yes, the only way to get rid of it is to close excel.. only other choice is to try hiding it.. so they cant see it

Comment: The issue is this: Up til Excel 2013, when I have this gray window (after _CurrentWorkbook.Close();_ ), _Workbooks.Open(xyz)_ will open xyz in that window and we have no empty window left. In 2016, the empty window remains, xyz is opened in another Excel window, so we have 2: an empty window and xyz

Comment: Hmm, my 2010 exhibits the same behavior as the 2016 in that sense. Im not getting 2 empty windows. Just the one.

Comment: I managed to localize when this occurs. It's true we will not see empty windows if we just close-open. Do this : 1. create a form 2. put a button inside. 3. On click event of that button insert the close-open code : CurrentWorkbook.Close(); //close A.xls
//some code
ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open("B.xls");
Only in this case will the problem arise on Excel 2016. On other versions or without an opening form on 2016, the problem does not occur.

Comment: I will investigate in the am, when im back with office 2016

Comment: Thanks in advance. This only occurs when another form is already opened when the close-open is performed. If no form is opened, the problem does not occur.

Comment: ExcelApplicaiton.Workbooks.Close(). brings me to the normal excel blank looking window, rather than an odd one.. I dont seem to have a CurrentWorkbook.Close option..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114605/discussion-between-bugfinder-and-kenny).

Comment: Simply Application.ActiveWorkbook. Is there any way we can close the container itself, the one with gray background ? That way when I open B.xls at least there will only be one instance.

Comment: come to the chat room

Comment: as Im opening a file, closing it, opening another and its reusing the same window